# Passing utf-8 encoded param from PHP to casper JS

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, encoding, casperjs

Via PHP shell_exec function I am passing the 'référencement'  word as param with this code

```
shell_exec('casperjs test.js --word='.escapeshellarg('référencement'));
```

but in casperjs when i log it I get some weired chars . In php everything is ok. How can i set charset utf8 in casperjs ? Or how do u see the solution ?

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't casperjs - how do write the log and how do you view that log? If you view the log on your terminal, then your terminal might not be set to utf-8 - or if you view it in an editor, that editor might not read the logfile as an utf-8 encoded file.

Comment: I am viewing it in my browser . Where my php header points utf8

Comment: echo $LANG in the terminal returns en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code I came up with .

```
shell_exec('LANG=en_US.utf-8; casperjs test.js --word='.escapeshellarg('référencement'));
```